# Cannot Login after extending User class generated by EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I would like to ask some help to figure out whats happening to my Login page.

I have a class named **User.cs** generated by EF

```
public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.PersonnelInfo = new HashSet<PersonnelInfo>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<PersonnelInfo> PersonnelInfo { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
```

To add a validation to those properties I add a new class named **UserMd.cs**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {

    }

    public class UserMetadata
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role is required.")]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Client ID")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client ID is required.")]
        public int AccountId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PersonnelInfo> PersonnelInfo { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    }
```

What I wanted to do is to extend my User class properties and base on my research I can extend my User class by adding additional partial class so I create **UserPropertyExtended.cs**

```
public partial class User
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } 
    }
```

My problem occured when I add validation to **ConfirmPassword** property.
I cannot Login to my application.
If I remove the validation everything is fine.

I don't want to add another column to my table that's why I extend my class User.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: IT would help if you could give more information that "I cannot Login to my application", why not? Do you get an error? However if you don't want ConfirmPassword in your database you should add the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Comment: Hi @BenRobinson,

There's no error occured when I try to login.
I used database first approach.
I tried this
code public partial class User
    {
        [NotMapped]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } 
    } code 

but still I cannot Login.

Thanks to your respond.

Comment: Yes, but what is the error message or exception or result of the login operation?  Have you set a debug breakpoint in your code to check?

Comment: Dear Sir @BenRobinson,

I tried to removed one by one the validations and it seems that `code` Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation do not match.")]`code`

caused my problem.

Comment: @AinneAvila When you say "i cannot log in", do you actually mean "validation failes on the ConfirmPassword property", if so what is the validation error, what are the values of the 2 properties that are being compared?

Comment: Dear sir @BenRobinson,

I used the ConfirmPassword for my Registration Page.

I compared Password and ConfirmPassword fields in Registration.

In my Login Page, I only have Client ID, Username, Password fields.

Comment: I tried to Debug my application and it end up in 
 `code` if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(); `code`

In my AccountController I have this:

`code`
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
if (!UserRepositoryCmd.IsUserExist(user.Username, user.Password, user.AccountId))return View();
Session["Username"] = user.Username;
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
`code`
so based on my understanding the model is not valid.

No error or exception appeared.

Comment: ModelState is a dictionary, if IsValid = false then it contains a list of all the val;idation error, inspect it in a debugger and find out what it contains, that will tell you the problem.

Comment: Sir @BenRobinson,
I don't understand the problem I do not used the ConfirmPassword in Login Page. I trace the ModelState error and the ConfirmPassword expect a value that's the reason why the ModelState failed.
I set the @Html.ValidationSummary(false,"My Error Message") and it shows
---------------
My Error Message:
The Confirm password field is required.
The password and confirmation do not match.
The user has related information and cannot be deleted.
---------------

The error occured in Login Page.
Please advice what I am going to do.

Thank you very much.
Really appreciate the help sir.

Comment: Ask yourself the question "do i need to validate the login credentials", I suspect the answer is no, if the credentials are valid then the user can login, if they are not then they can't. Remove the `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();` from your login action, it is not doing anything other than validating properties you don't care about.

Comment: Dear Sir @BenRobinson,

Thank you for you time for answering my questions.
I already fixed the problem by putting ModelState.Remove()

`code` 
ModelState.Remove("ConfirmPassword")
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
`code`

Thank you very much.